# Resetar eventos do jQuery ao enviar mensagem ao usuário

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando enviar uma mensagem ao usuário utilizando jQuery e esconde-la de forma automática após alguns segundos. Esse procedimento ocorre perfeitamente a menos que o evento ocorra em tempo inferior ao tempo de ocultar a mensagem, fazendo com que a mensagem não chegue sincronizada com o evento. Para realizar um teste clique multiplas vezes no link para acompanhar o resultado.

Segue o exemplo:

```js
$('#id').click(function(){

    $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success">ALERTA</div>').hide().fadeIn();
    $("#msg").delay(5000).fadeOut();
  
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="id" class="btn">alerta</a>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

OBS: Qualquer outra solução para resolver esse problema é bem vinda.

Comment: Testa juntando um `.stop()` assim: `$("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success">ALERTA</div>').hide().stop().fadeIn();`

Comment: Posso considerar a resposta como válida, mas não atendeu totalmente o esperado, pois após multiplos toques acabaram saindo da sincronia do evento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens várias opções. Podes juntar um `.stop()` assim: `$("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success">ALERTA</div>').hide().stop().fadeIn();` e dessa maneira interrompes animações em curso.

```js
$('#id').click(function(){

    $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success">ALERTA</div>').hide().stop().fadeIn();
    $("#msg").delay(5000).fadeOut();
  
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="id" class="btn">alerta</a>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Ou podes criar uma flag que impede novos clicks antes desse fadeOut ter acabado. Assim:

```js
var avisado = false;
$('#id').click(function(){
    if (avisado) return false;
    $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success">ALERTA</div>').hide().fadeIn();
    $("#msg").delay(5000).fadeOut(function(){ avisado = false;});
    avisado = true;  
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="id" class="btn">alerta</a>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Outra opção que [o @wallace sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49953/resetar-eventos-do-jquery-ao-enviar-mensagem-ao-usu%C3%A1rio/49954?noredirect=1#comment101358_49954) é guardar essa informação no próprio elemento atravéz de uma propriedade `.data()`, nesse caso o código poderia ser assim:

```
$('#id').click(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var avisado = self.data('avisado');
    if (avisado) return false;
    $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success">ALERTA</div>').hide().fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(function () {
        self.data('avisado', false);
    });
    self.data('avisado', true);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fepkksm1/1/

Comment: OBS:Somente a 2ª opção atendeu totalmente o meu problema

Comment: Ao invés de usar a variável global `avisado`, você poderia ter simplesmente usado o `data` no código. Ex: `$(this).data('avisado', true)`. Fica mais elegante :)

Comment: poderia demonstrar o exemplo no jsfiddle?

Comment: @adrianosymphony juntei um jsFiddle

Comment: @WallaceMaxters boa sugestão! juntei essa ideia na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma boa de fazer, em vez de criar o div dinamicamente dentro do msg, coloque o #msg como a propria div, esconda ela e só mostre no click.
eu preferi fazer pelo display:none do css, mas você pode fazer pela função hide() do jQuery.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="id" class="btn">alerta</a>
<div id="msg" class="alert alert-success"> ALERTA </div>
```

CSS:

```
#msg{
display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#id').click(function(){
   $("#msg").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Valeu $Gabriel Rodrigues, está solução também me atendeu perfeitamente e de forma mais simples.